# How to test Sequelize in nestjs model

Tags: nestjs, sequelize-typescript

How can I test the Sequelize param, like

```
    constructor(
        private sequelize: Sequelize,
        @InjectModel(User) private userModel: typeof User,
        @InjectModel(Shop) private shopModel: typeof Shop
     ) {}
```

for the models I use

```
    { provide: getModelToken(User), useValue: User },
    { provide: getModelToken(Shop), useValue: Shop },
```

How can I add Sequelize as provider?

It gives me this error:

```
 Potential solutions:
    - If Sequelize is a provider, is it part of the current TestingRootModule?
    - If Sequelize is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TestingRootModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing Sequelize */ ]
      })
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have found the solution, you just have to add this to the provider

```
{
  provide: Sequelize,
  useValue: sequelizeMock
}
```